# Additional Scroll Bar Below the Header of JQuery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables (Jquery).

Using the code i am getting a horizontal Scroll bar above my footer of the table as in the [Link](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html) :

```
 "sScrollX": "100%",
 "sScrollXInner": "120%",
 "bScrollCollapse": true,
```

Now i want to get another Scroll Bar below the Header also.
Help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to add another `container` which has a `fixed width like 1000px` with `overflow auto`. And if the content `overflows` by `1000px` then you will able to show the `scroller` in the `container`

Like:

**CSS**

`.newcontainer{width:1000px;overflow:auto;}`

**HTML**

```
<div class="newcontainer">
    <!-- Your div having the datatable-->
</div>
```

Comment: This will create a scroll bar.. But i want the scroll bar to be placed below the Header. Is this possible ?

Comment: @PravinKumar I think its not possible because here the `scrollbar` is applied on `div.dataTables_scrollBody`, and `scrollbar` always shown in the `bottom` of the `element`.

Answer (score 14):

Add the following code to the Datatable initialization:

```
"fnInitComplete": function(){

    // Enable THEAD scroll bars
    $('.dataTables_scrollHead').css('overflow', 'auto');

    // Sync THEAD scrolling with TBODY
    $('.dataTables_scrollHead').on('scroll', function () {
        $('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
    });                    
},
```

Reference: [DataTables plug-in - Display scrollbar below tfoot tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843811/datatables-plug-in-display-scrollbar-below-tfoot-tag)

jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/3xvpznd3/

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A slight update to the above code by Joseph:

When you add a Thead scroll bar and change its position on scroll event, it gets called thousands of times in a minute which will make your browser respond slowly resulting in a slow scrolling X horizontal bar. To avoid this add throttle like shown below which will basically make sure that the function is executed once in 100 milli seconds.

```
"fnInitComplete": function(){

                        // Enable THEAD scroll bars
                        $('.dataTables_scrollHead').css('overflow', 'auto');

                        // Sync THEAD scrolling with TBODY
                        $('.dataTables_scrollHead').on('scroll', $.throttle( 100,function () {
                            $('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
                        }));                    
                    }
```