# How to Synchronize Scroll Between two windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a popup window in my site that show additional information about the elements been show in the main screen. I need to syncronize the scrolling between the two windows, in a way that when the user scroll one of the window , the other window is automatticaly scrolled in the same ammount.

I was able to do that using jquery scroll event, and using the scrollTop function to set the scroll position. something like this:

```
$("#localDiv").scroll(function() {        
    var scrollPos = $("#localDiv").scrollTop();
    $("targetElement").scrollTop( scrollPos );
});
```

I've simplified the actual code, because I have to do some work to reach the elements in another window, but this is not the question.

The problem is, this code works fine in Chrome and IE, but in FireFox the scrolling gets really slow.

I've created an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/Lv2dw787/4/. The problem seems to ocurr with DIV's in the same page as well. You can note that when the scrolling syncing is disabled, the speed turn back to normal.

Does anyone have a clue on how to fix this on FireFox?

---

Edit after Dave Chen answer:

The accepted answer solved my problem, but it has a catch. I first tried to do this:

```
lock = true;
try {
    var scrollPos = $("#contentDivA").scrollTop();
    $("#contentDivB").scrollTop( scrollPos );
}
finally
{
    lock = false; 
}
```

But the `$("#contentDivB").scrollTop( scrollPos );` line seems to generate a scroll event on divB only after the current function finishes executing, so the finally part of try..finally was executing before that. So I had to this:

```
lock = true;

var scrollPos = $("#contentDivA").scrollTop();
$("#contentDivB").scrollTop( scrollPos );
```

and on DivB scroll event:

```
if (lock)
    lock = false;
else {
   (Do the scroll on DivA)
}
```

Comment: Works fine on my Mac Firefox. Have you tried a second computer and confirmed it isn't local to your install? Is your Firefox just slow, period?

Comment: I can confirm it work slower on FireFox on mac too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because of two reasons:

1. Firefox does smoothing on its scrolling
2. jQuery's `scrollTop` will trigger events

Let's look at some pseudo-code:

```
When divA is scrolled -> scroll divB to the same spot
When divB is scrolled -> scroll divA to the same spot
```

The problem is that when you `scroll divA or divB to the same spot`, it will also cause the `when` to happen again.

So for example, when you scroll divA, this is what happens:

```
scroll divA -> scroll divB to the same spot -> scroll divA to the same spot
```

This causes divA to stick to the same spot after scrolling a little, and thus what causes the sluggish effect in firefox.

A solution is to ignore scrolling events when you scroll:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var ignore = false;

    $("#contentDivA").scroll(function() {  
        var tmpIgnore = ignore;
        ignore = false;
        if (!tmpIgnore && $("#chkSyncEnabled")[0].checked)
        {
            var scrollPos = $("#contentDivA").scrollTop();
            scrollTop($("#contentDivB"), scrollPos);
        }
    });

    $("#contentDivB").scroll(function() {
        var tmpIgnore = ignore;
        ignore = false;
        if (!tmpIgnore && $("#chkSyncEnabled")[0].checked)
        {
            console.log("here");
            var scrollPos = $("#contentDivB").scrollTop();
            scrollTop($("#contentDivA"), scrollPos);
        }
    });

    function scrollTop(el, position) {
        ignore = true;
        el.scrollTop(position);
    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/exzmqdv9/)

Comment: I see it running on the example you've send, but i can't understand why. :). If ignore is initially set to true, and tmpIgnore is set to ignore, and the if statement is "if (!tmpIgnore" , how the code inside the if statement is executing?

Comment: Oh, Now i get it, this will only happen the first time.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it doesn't matter what the initial value of `ignore` is set to. What matters is that ignore will act as a flag, detecting when it's a human scrolling, or when the computer scrolls the other div.

Comment: When it's the computer scrolling the div (to match the other one), it won't try to scroll the other div. And when it's the human scrolling, then it make the other div match.