# table footer does not align with the body and header when using scroller in jQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am using jQuery [datatables](https://datatables.net/). I added [bootstrap select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) on the footer. My table looks as below :

[image]

As I have over 70 columns, I need to add scroll X to my datatable and also set a specific height to Scroll Y so that the table header will be fixed while scrolling.

when I add in my datatable the following :

```
"scrollY": 400,
"scrollX": true,
"scrollCollapse": true
```

but the [scroller](https://datatables.net/reference/option/scroller) messed up with the footer as you see below :
[image]

The footer is not aligned with the header and body and also it's fixed, when I scroll to left and right it's not synchronizing with the body and header. I can not see all the footer.

I tried multiple solutions suggested here like [display scrollbar below the footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843811/datatables-plug-in-display-scrollbar-below-tfoot-tag) also append the select in header table with .`appendTo( $(column.header()) )` instead of `$(column.footer()).empty()` but then the header was fixed...

I ended up using pure css by wrapping my table inside a `<div class="custom">` and style it this way

```
.custom { overflow-y: auto; height: 450px; }
.custom thead th { position: sticky; top: 0; }
```

and used Javascript to ensure tableHeader is fixed

```
var $th = $('.custom').find('thead th')
$('.custom').on('scroll', function() {
  $th.css('transform', 'translateY('+ this.scrollTop +'px)');
});
```

but the header is overlopping.

Any suggestions please what I need to adjust so that the scroller will not fixe my footer on my datatables ? Thank you very much.

Here is a demo of my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var liveTable = $('#liveTable').DataTable( {

    "scroller": true,
    "scrollY": 400,
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
    "searching": false,

    initComplete: function () { 

    this.api().columns().every( function () { 
      var column = this;
      var select = $('<select><option value="">All</option></select>')
          .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
          .on( 'change', function () {
            //
          } );

     column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
     select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' );
        } );

     select.selectpicker();

            });
        }        
} );







    

} );
```

```css
 th, td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.dataTables_scrollFoot{
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.17/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.17/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


           <table id="liveTable" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>COUNTRY_NAME</th>
            <th>COUNTRY_CODE</th>
            <th>TERRITORY</th>
            <th>MARKET</th>
            <th>REGION</th>
            <th>CustomerName</th>
            <th>STATUS</th>
            <th>OrderQty</th>
            <th>Crncy</th>
            <th>LocalPrice</th>
            <th>Dollarprice</th>
            <th>Europrice</th>
            <th>Poundprice</th>
            <th>Ship To</th>
            <th>Ship To Name</th>
            <th>Ship To House/ Street Number</th>
            <th>Ship To City</th>
            <th>Ship To Postal Code</th>
            <th>Ship To Region</th>
            <th>Ship To Telephone</th>
            <th>Ship To Email</th>
            <th>Ship To Country</th>
            <th>BillTo Number</th>
            <th>BillTo Name</th>
            <th>BillTo Street</th>
            <th>BilllTo City</th>
            <th>BillTo Postal code</th>
            <th>BillTo Country</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test1</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            <th>test2</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
            <th>COUNTRY_NAME</th>
            <th>COUNTRY_CODE</th>
            <th>TERRITORY</th>
            <th>MARKET</th>
            <th>REGION</th>
            <th>CustomerName</th>
            <th>STATUS</th>
            <th>OrderQty</th>
            <th>Crncy</th>
            <th>LocalPrice</th>
            <th>Dollarprice</th>
            <th>Europrice</th>
            <th>Poundprice</th>
            <th>Ship To</th>
            <th>Ship To Name</th>
            <th>Ship To House/ Street Number</th>
            <th>Ship To City</th>
            <th>Ship To Postal Code</th>
            <th>Ship To Region</th>
            <th>Ship To Telephone</th>
            <th>Ship To Email</th>
            <th>Ship To Country</th>
            <th>BillTo Number</th>
            <th>BillTo Name</th>
            <th>BillTo Street</th>
            <th>BilllTo City</th>
            <th>BillTo Postal code</th>
            <th>BillTo Country</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        
    </table>
```